# Updating angular.js view in an interval

Tags: string, angularjs, random, settimeout

I want to make something like a shuffler with angular.js. The idea is to upgrade the view every 200miliseconds at the begining with a new string and slowly increase the delay until the moment where strings are not changing anymore and one is selected. My problem is that angular has something like a defense against so rapidly changing values, because when I execute this code in my controller, only the first random string is shown.

```
$scope.shuffleStrings = function () {

        var arrayOfStrings = ['this', 'that', 'foo', 'bar', 'bim', 'bam', 'bum'];
        var delay = 100;

        var updateValue = function () {         

            $scope.crntString = arrayOfStrings[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayOfStrings.length)];

            if(delay <= 1000) {
                delay += (10/100)*delay
                setTimeout(updateValue, delay);
            }
        }

        updateValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $timeout instead of setTimeout. Read more: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Answer (score 1):

use $interval for this...

```
    $scope.arrayOfStrings = ['this', 'that', 'foo', 'bar', 'bim', 'bam', 'bum'];
    $scope.delay = 100;

    var updateValue = function () {         

        $scope.crntString = $scope.arrayOfStrings[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
             $scope.arrayOfStrings.length)];

        if($scope.delay <= 1000) {
            $scope.delay += (10/100)*$scope.delay
        }
    }

    var interval = $interval(updateValue,200);

   $scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
       $interval.cancel(interval);
   });
```

your string is not getting updated because you are using setTimeout, use $timeout which is more angular way...

Comment: but I am willing to change the delay to the next function, check what I have used and see if it is meeting the standarts or suggest improvements ;)

Comment: My answer. Sorry, I am not lightning fast.

Comment: did this answer worked?? if yes can you please accept/upvote??

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to use a simple interval, but a Timeout, because I am willing to change the delay every time. The problem was that I execute another function, which is not an angular function, therefore values do not get updated. My solution is a simple `$scope.$apply();`. Here is the full code:

```
$scope.shuffleStrings = function () {

        var arrayOfStrings = ['this', 'that', 'foo', 'bar', 'bim', 'bam', 'bum'];
        var delay = 100;

        var updateValue = function () {         

            $scope.crntString = arrayOfStrings[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayOfStrings.length)];
            $scope.$apply();

            if(delay <= 1000) {
                delay += (10/100)*delay
                setTimeout(updateValue, delay);
            }
        }

        updateValue();
    }
```